# Access other object fields in StreamField / RichText field/block in wagtail

Tags: wagtail

I would like to do the following:

1. Create some django model (or wagtail page) that contains data.
2. Create another Page type that includes a StreamField or RichtextField.
   3.
3. When the author or editor enters text in this field, he/she can have the information of this appear somewhere in the rendered output of the text. Preferably using common template techniques.

So, lets say, we have a model like this:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
```

Then I have a normal page that uses a StreamField:

```
class NormalPage(Page):
    body = StreamField(block_types=[
        ('paragraph', blocks.RichTextBlock()),
    ])

    content_panels = Page.content_panels + [
        StreamFieldPanel('body')
    ]
```

I would like for the editor to choose which Person he/she would like from the database and the be able to do something like this in the RichTextBlock:

```
{{ person.name }}
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

In order to be able to choose a plain Django model, register it as a snippet as shown [here](https://docs.wagtail.io/en/v2.5.1/getting_started/tutorial.html?highlight=%40register_snippet#categories), and then use [SnippetChooserPanel](https://docs.wagtail.io/en/v2.5.1/reference/pages/panels.html#module-wagtail.snippets.edit_handlers) to choose the person:

```
from wagtail.snippets.models import register_snippet

@register_snippet
class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
```

And then if you want to associate a particular person with a particular page:

```
from wagtail.snippets.edit_handlers import SnippetChooserPanel

class NormalPage(Page):
    body = StreamField(block_types=[
        ('paragraph', blocks.RichTextBlock()),
    ])
    person = models.ForeignKeyField(Person)

    content_panels = Page.content_panels + [
        StreamFieldPanel('body'),
        SnippetChooserPanel('person'),
    ]
```

Comment: hi dan,
thanks for the reply. however, this does not solve my original problem.

what i would need is a way to make the data associated with the chosen 'Person' available to the editor of the 'body' streamfield. your solution makes this data available in the template of the page. but the editor does not have access to that.

Comment: This video about customizing Draftail might help you:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A4M0MEtE_H0&list=PLMQHMcNi6ocsS8Bfnuy_IDgJ4bHRRrvub&index=30&t=0s